# Memory allocation error for structs with members that are function pointers and void pointers

Tags: c, memory-management, function-pointers, void-pointers

I have written a straightforward C code that uses an engine to run two different algorithms depending on user input. It uses function pointers to the algorithm methods and objects. There is a nasty memory bug somewhere that I can not track down, so maybe I am allocating memory in the wrong way. What is going wrong?

Below is (the relevant parts of) a minimal working example of the code.

**main.c**

```
#include "engine.h"

int main()
{
  char *id = "one";

  Engine_t eng;

  Engine_init(&eng);
  Engine_select_algorithm(eng, id);
  Engine_run(eng);
}
```

**engine.h**

```
typedef struct _Engine *Engine_t;
```

**engine.c**

```
#include "engine.h"
#include "algorithm_one.h"
#include "algorithm_two.h"

typedef struct _Engine
{ 
  void *p_algorithm;

  void (*init)(Engine_t);
  void (*run)(Engine_t);

} Engine;

void Engine_init(Engine_t *eng)
{
  *eng = malloc(sizeof(Engine));

  (*eng)->p_algorithm = NULL;
}

void Engine_select_algorithm(Engine_t eng, char *id)
{
  if ( strcmp(id, "one") == 0 )
    {
      eng->init = Algorithm_one_init;
      eng->run  = Algorithm_one_run;
    }
  else if ( strcmp(id, "two") == 0 )
    {
      eng->init = Algorithm_two_init;
      eng->run  = Algorithm_two_run;
    }
  else
    {
      printf("Unknown engine %s.\n", id); exit(0);
    }

  eng->init(eng);
}

void Engine_run(Engine_t eng)
{
  eng->run(eng);
}

void Engine_set_algorithm(Engine_t eng, void *p)
{
  eng->p_algorithm = p;
}

void Engine_get_algorithm(Engine_t eng, void *p)
{
  p = eng->p_algorithm;
}
```

**algorithm_one.h**

```
typedef struct _A_one *A_one_t;
```

**algorithm_one.c**

```
#include "engine.h"
#include "algorithm_one.h"

typedef struct _A_one
{ 
  float value;
} A_one;

void Algorithm_one_init(Engine_t eng)
{
  A_one_t aone;
  aone = malloc(sizeof(A_one));
  aone->value = 13.0;

  //int var = 10;

  Engine_set_algorithm(eng, &aone);
}

void Algorithm_one_run(Engine_t eng)
{  
  A_one_t aone;
  Engine_get_algorithm(eng, &aone);

  printf("I am running algorithm one with value %f.\n", aone->value);
  // The code for algorithm one goes here.
}
```

The code for **algorithm_two.h** and **algorithm_two.c** are identical to the algorithm one files.

There must be a memory bug involved, because the code runs as given, but if I uncomment the

```
//int var = 10;
```

line in **algoritm_one.c** the code crashes with a segmentation fault.

Comment: Your `Engine_get_algorithm` function will not actually get anything, since `p` is local to the function. You need to either return the algorithm, or pass `p` by pointer.

Comment: Argh, a pointer `typedef`. This makes your code really hard to read.

Comment: @ Sander De Dycker Thanks, you are right, and I have made modifications according to the answer from David Heffernan.

Comment: @JensGustedt If it was hard to write, it should be hard to read. ;) No, seriously, I think it is a good way to have a clear separation between the interface in .h and the implementation in .c.

Comment: Hm, this is just hiding things. In C when you see an interface without a `*` you are expecting things to be passed by value. In most projects such an interface wouldn't pass reviewing.

Comment: I am sure you are correct. Luckily, in academia, most of the time code  only need to pass the (mild) scrutiny of the individual researcher (=myself). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the wrong thing to `Engine_set_algorithm`. You are passing the address of a local variable rather than the address of the algorithm. You need to write:

```
Engine_set_algorithm(eng, aone);
```

And also `Engine_get_algorithm` is wrong. You are passed a pointer by value and modify that pointer. So the caller cannot see that modification. You need it to be:

```
void Engine_get_algorithm(Engine_t eng, void **p)
{
  *p = eng->p_algorithm;
}
```

I think your code would be easier if you defined a type to represent an algorithm. That type would be just a `void*`, but it would make the code much easier to read. What's more, I would make `Engine_get_algorithm` return the algorithm.

```
algorithm Engine_get_algorithm(Engine_t eng)
{
    return eng->p_algorithm;
}

void Engine_set_algorithm(Engine_t eng, algorithm alg)
{
    eng->p_algorithm = alg;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I should have spotted that one myself. Your other suggestions are excellent as well. The code works as intended now. Defining an algorithm type for readability is definitely a good idea. Many humble thanks for a swift and concise answer.